# Getting bad request and unexpected token in json at position 0

Tags: angular, angular8

I am creating a attendance manger when I call checkin api I get error for unexpected token at position 0
 found something from my browser.It shows BAD request. I am not sure what is happening.Please suggest.

component.html

```
<div class="col-xl-2 col-md-2 btn btn-success" (click)="Attendance()">
        <h5>{{ attendanceTime | date: "mediumTime"}}</h5>
        <h5>{{attendanceValue}}</h5>

    <form [formGroup]="attendanceForm" >
            <input type="hidden" formControlName="checkIn" [ngModel]="checkIn"> 
            <input type="hidden" formControlName="checkOut" [ngModel]="checkOut"> 
    </form>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
 Attendance(){
    if(this.attendanceValue === 'Check-in'){
      this.checkIn = this.attendanceTime;
      this.attendanceValue = "Check-out";
      console.log("checkin     "+ this.checkIn);
      var formData: any = new FormData();
      formData.append("checkIn", this.attendanceForm.get('checkIn').value);
      this.cs.callAPI(formData, "attendance" ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(this.attendanceForm.value)
        let body = response.text();
        if (body.status === 1) {
          console.log("response.message" + body.message);
          this.myapp.showSuccessAlert = true;
          this.myapp.successMsg = body.message;
          this.myapp.isLoadingResults = false;
        } else {
          console.log("response.message" + response.message);
          this.myapp.showErrorAlert = true;
          this.myapp.errorMsg = body.message;
          this.myapp.isLoadingResults = false;
        }
      })
    } else{
      this.checkOut = this.attendanceTime;
      console.log("checkout    "+ this.checkOut);
      this.attendanceValue = "Check-in";
    }
}
```

callAPI method from common service

```
callAPI(data, apiFunction) {
    let formdata = data;
    console.log("formdata" + formdata)
    let url: string = this.baseUrl + apiFunction; 
    return this.http
      .post<any>(url, formdata)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/attendance 400 (Bad Request)
core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3000/attendance", ok: false, …}

message: "Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0"
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to add () on ngModel  : [(ngModel)] ?

Comment: @Yin after adding() get same error

Comment: provide your callAPI function too.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki please check

Comment: @mic `HttpErrorResponse
error: {message: "Not authenticated."}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/attendance: 401 Unauthorized"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "http://localhost:3000/attendance"`

Comment: What's your formData? Is it JSON? If it is, stringify it while posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never transform your data to JSON format, that's why the string is not a valid JSON string (and the parser tells you exactly that).

So you need to convert it to a JSON string, simply calling `JSON.stringify` on your object, giving you this instead of your call:

```js
return this.http
  .post<any>(url, JSON.stringify(formdata))
  .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```